# yii2:Conditional dispaly/show field dependent on Action

Tags: javascript, php, validation, yii2

How can I add a condition at field level in form or at validation rules in model, that the field will remain hidden on `action/create` and shown on `action/update` only.

for example I have a field, which I want to show only in the update screen and not on create screen.

```
$form->field($model, 'discharged')->checkBox();
```

Ok I have updated the code as suggested in the comments like in the **Model**

```
public function scenarios()
    {
        $scenarios = parent::scenarios();
        $scenarios['update'] = ['discharged', 'discharge_date'];
        return $scenarios;
    }
```

and then in the rules

```
[['discharged', 'discharge_date'], 'required', 'on' => 'update'],
```

and in my update action in controller I have added:

```
$model->scenario = 'update';
```

But the above code make the fields required in update scenario, what I want that the fields remain hidden in create action and only show on update.

**update**
form.php

```
<?php 

    echo Tabs::widget([
    'items' => [
     .....

    '<div class="col-lg-6">'.
                if(Yii::$app->controller->action->id == 'update') {
                $form->field($model, 'discharged')->checkBox()
                }
                        .'</div>'.
```

I am out of Idea, how I should go about it to just show the fields in update screen.
Thanks.

Comment: You should simply use scenarios and `if` statements... Read more http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-models.html#scenarios

Comment: Hi Soju - I have updated the question using the scenario, can you suggest how I can show the fields on update screen only. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1)** You can render different views for forms.

`create` view:

```
$this->render('_create-form', ['model' => $model];
```

`update` view:

```
$this->render('_update-form', ['model' => $model];
```

**2)** In case if you want use only one form and prevent code duplication you can add check for needed action:

`form` view:

```
use Yii;

...

if ($this->context->action->id == 'update') {
    echo $form->field($model, 'discharged')->checkBox();
}
```

For validation use scenarios as suggested in comments.

Comment: Thanks @arogachev - You mean what I am trying to acheive, I don't need scenarios at all.

Comment: Scenario could be useful for validation

Comment: Hi @arogachev - I am having this field in tabs -widget- when including your code in the widget it is generating the syntax error. I have update the question showing the code for form.php. Can you see what is wrong in the syntax.

Comment: Okay need to modify the code using ternary Operator. Thanks Arogachev

Comment: @soju - I was looking for the solution arogachev provided, not validation as per my question - any way thanks to both of you.